# SQL Server 2005 - column names based on variable passed in pivot query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have following query which takes 2 parameters.

1. YearNumber
2. MonthNumber

In my pivot query, I am trying to select columns based on `@Year_Rtl` variable. I need to select data for the year passed, last year and last last year. Since the data being displayed on UI is table format divided by `@Year_Rtl`, I decided to write a pivot query for that as below.

In the query, it works fine if I hard code `[@Year_Rtl], [@Year_Rtl - 1], [@Year_Rtl - 2]` to `[2012], [2011], [2010]`. But since the year passed can be anything, I want columns to be named dynamically.

```
DECLARE @Month_Rtl int  
DECLARE @Year_Rtl int  

SET @Year_Rtl = 2012
SET @Month_Rtl = 1

SELECT  
    'Data 1', [@Year_Rtl], [@Year_Rtl - 1], [@Year_Rtl - 2]
FROM
   (SELECT [Yr_No], Qty
    FROM dbo.Table1 t
    WHERE (t.Col1 = 10) AND   
    (t.Col2 = '673') AND  
    ((t.Mth_No = @Month_Rtl AND t.Yr_No = @Year_Rtl) OR 
     (t.Mth_No = 12 AND t.Yr_No IN (@Year_Rtl - 1, @Year_Rtl - 2)))  
   ) p PIVOT (SUM(Qty)
              FOR [Yr_No] IN ([@Year_Rtl], [@Year_Rtl-1], [@Year_Rtl-2])
             ) AS pvt
```

Above query throws following errors:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to smallint.
>   The incorrect value "@Year_Rtl" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.
>   Invalid column name '@Year_Rtl - 1'.
>   Invalid column name '@Year_Rtl - 2'.

Comment: The columns involved in a `PIVOT` can't be variable, outside the use of dynamic SQL. Yes, it sucks. It's just the way it is.

Comment: I am able to create the entire query as dynamic SQL. Wondering if it will hit the performance?

Comment: As far as I know, Dynamic column pivoting can only be achieved with dynamic SQL - of course it won't have as good performance as a stored query plan but its either that or not having the query work at all.

Comment: @vince_sql why do you think performance will be worse? Why do you think you can't store a query plan if you're using dynamic SQL? Of course you can write your dynamic SQL in a way that defeats this, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use dynamic SQL, I'd go with a macro-replacement approach. You're identifying areas of the query that must be dynamically replaced with placeholders (e.g. `$$Year_Rtl`) and then calculating their replacement values below. I find that it keeps the SQL statement easy to follow.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVarChar(2000);
SELECT @SQL = N'
  SELECT  
      ''Data 1'', [$$Year_Rtl], [$$Year_RtlM1], [$$Year_RtlM2]
  FROM
     (SELECT [Yr_No], Qty
      FROM dbo.Table1 t
      WHERE (t.Col1 = 10) AND   
      (t.Col2 = ''673'') AND  
      ((t.Mth_No = $$Month_Rtl AND t.Yr_No = $$Year_Rtl) OR 
       (t.Mth_No = 12 AND t.Yr_No IN ($$Year_RtlM1, $$Year_RtlM2)))  
     ) p PIVOT (SUM(Qty)
                FOR [Yr_No] IN ([$$Year_Rtl], [$$Year_RtlM1], [$$Year_RtlM2])
               ) AS pvt';

SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '$$Year_RtlM2', @Year_Rtl - 2);
SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '$$Year_RtlM1', @Year_Rtl - 1);
SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '$$Year_Rtl', @Year_Rtl);
SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '$$Month_Rtl', @Month_Rtl);

PRINT @SQL;
-- Uncomment the next line to allow the built query to execute...
--EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL;
```

Comment: Do you know how can i select multiple columns and still get one row? Like Select [Yr_No], Qty, Amount. I tried but it gives me 2 rows and in first row Amount is null and in other row Qty is null.

Answer (score 1):

Since *consuming* code will *also* have to be flaky under this scheme (e.g. selecting columns based on "position" rather than name) - why not normalize the columns by performing a `DATEDIFF(year,Yr_No,@Year_Rtl)`, and work from there? Those columns will always be `0`, `-1` and `-2`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Dynamic SQL Pivoting.

I recommend reading Itzik Ben-Gan's T-SQL Fundamentals where he goes over how to do this.

Alternatively try [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) if you don't want to buy the book.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

First getting the columns with a tally function like this:

```
DECLARE @Month_Rtl int,  
        @Year_Rtl int,
        @Year_Rtl_Start INT,
        @cols VARCHAR(MAX),
        @values VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Year_Rtl = 2012
SET @Month_Rtl = 1
SET @Year_Rtl_Start=2009

;WITH Years ( n ) AS (
        SELECT @Year_Rtl_Start UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Years WHERE n < @Year_Rtl )
SELECT
    @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(n),
                     QUOTENAME(n)),
    @values = COALESCE(@values + ','+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(100)),
                     CAST(n AS VARCHAR(100)))
FROM
    Years
ORDER BY n DESC
```

The variable `@cols` contains the columns that is in the pivot and the variable `@values` contains the years for the `IN`. The `@Year_Rtl` is the end year and the `@Year_Rtl_Start` is the start for you range.

Then declaring and executing the dynamic pivot like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT  
    ''Data 1'', '+@cols+'
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            [Yr_No], Qty
        FROM 
            dbo.Table1 t
        WHERE 
            t.Col1 = 10 
            AND t.Col2 = ''673''
            AND 
            (
                (
                    t.Mth_No = '+CAST(@Month_Rtl AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                    AND t.Yr_No = '+CAST(@Year_Rtl AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                ) 
                OR 
                (
                    t.Mth_No = 12 
                    AND t.Yr_No IN ('+@values+'))
                )  
    ) p 
    PIVOT 
    (
        SUM(Qty)
        FOR [Yr_No] IN ('+@cols+')
    ) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```